# Vb.net error "'InvalidArgument=Value of '0' is not valid for 'index'. Parameter name: index'"

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

I know why I am getting the error "'InvalidArgument=Value of '0' is not valid for 'index'.Parameter name: index'" Its because of my sql statement not returning any values. The problem is how I do program vb.net so if there is no values I am not going to run into that problem.

```
Private Sub showdata1()

    Dim queryStr As String = "SELECT student.id,firstname,lastname FROM Student INNER JOIN Class_Student ON student.id = class_student.ID where class_student.classid=" & ListView1.SelectedItems(0).SubItems(0).Text & ""
    Dim con As New OleDbConnection("provider=microsoft.jet.oledb.4.0;data source=C:\Users\XXXX\XXXX\XXX\XXX.mdb")
    con.Open()
    Dim cmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand(queryStr, con)

    Dim read As OleDbDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()

    If queryStr = "" Then

    Else
        While read.Read()

            Dim item As ListViewItem = New ListViewItem()
            item.Text = CStr(read.Item("StudentId"))

            item.SubItems.Add(read.Item("FirstName"))
            item.SubItems.Add(read.Item("LastName"))

            ListView2.Items.Add(item)

        End While
    End If

    con.Close()
End Sub
```

Comment: Use parameters to avoid sql injection and formatting errors.  What does the debugger say is the value of `ListView1.SelectedItems(0).SubItems(0).Text`?

Comment: There wont be any value in the that listview. So Zero

Comment: Your query prints like this: "...where class_student.classid="  Use parameters.  `...where class_student.classid=?`  Then, `cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", ListView1.SelectedItems(0).SubItems(0).Text)`

Comment: The ItemSelectionChanged event is dangerous, it also fires with no items are selected and that's going to bomb this code.  We can't see it.  Anyhoo, put If ListView1.SelectedItems.Count = 0 Then Exit Sub at the start of this method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Double check in your database for the datatype of class_student.classid. I have followed your lead and used VarChar as datatype but when I see ID I think Long or Interger.

```
Private Sub showdata1()
    'Thanks to Lectere and Hans Passant
    If ListView1.SelectedItems.Count = 0 OrElse String.IsNullOrEmpty(ListView1.SelectedItems(0).SubItems(0).Text) Then
        Return
    End If
    'It is OK to use parameter names with OleDB and I think it makes the code clearer.
    'Just remember that the additions to the parameters collection must be in the same
    'order as they appear in the query.
    Dim queryStr As String = "SELECT student.id,firstname,lastname 
                              FROM Student 
                              INNER JOIN Class_Student ON student.id = class_student.ID 
                              WHERE class_student.classid= @ClassID;"

    Using con As New OleDbConnection("provider=microsoft.jet.oledb.4.0;data source=C:\Users\XXXX\XXXX\XXX\XXX.mdb")
        Using cmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand(queryStr, con)
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@ClassID", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = ListView1.SelectedItems(0).SubItems(0).Text
            con.Open()
            Using read As OleDbDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
                While read.Read()
                    Dim item As New ListViewItem()
                    item.Text = CStr(read.Item("StudentId"))
                    item.SubItems.Add(CStr(read.Item("FirstName")))
                    item.SubItems.Add(CStr(read.Item("LastName")))
                    ListView1.Items.Add(item)
                End While
            End Using 'Close and dispose reader
        End Using 'Close and dispose command
    End Using 'Close and dispose connection
End Sub
```

Comment: Ok so this kinda of works. But when you cant select the listview items now. It will now error, when before it will give you all of the students that are in the class. ...'No value given for one or more required parameters.'

Comment: If nothing is selected it should simply return to the calling code. What error are you getting?

Comment: Ok, I am new to this website. Sorry how can I post screenshots of my program.

Comment: You don't need a screenshot, just the text of the error.

Comment: The posted question used `ListView1.SelectedItems(0).SubItems(0).Text` as the value of the classID parameter. Now you are using a `ListBox` Of course that changes things. BTW, have you verified the datatype of the classID column in the database. If you confirm that this is a ListBox I will Edit my answer to reflect this.

Comment: Its my bad sorry, it is a 'listview'. I was typing something else. It is a number

Comment: Let's try `cmd.Parameters.Add("@ClassID", OleDbType.Numeric).Value = CInt(ListView1.SelectedItems(0).SubItems(0).Text)` in place of the line with`.VarChar` As far as the error goes are you sure you have that first If block in your code?

Comment: I tweaked the code you provided me and it works! Thanks again! This community is really great!

Answer (score 0):

The andalso is a good way to first test if it's not 'nothing', and then check the value;

```
if queryStr isnot nothing andalso queryStr.lenght > 0 then
```

The second part of the if statement, after andalso, will not be evaluated unless the first condition is met. Thus not creating a runtime error if it's nothing...

Comment: Yes, good use of `AndAlso` but in this case `queryStr` cannot be `Nothing` as it is clearly assigned just a few lines up.